# Flutter How to store a list of values with same variable in shared preferences and then get the specific value from there

Tags: arrays, flutter, sharedpreferences

I have a variable *abc* and value is coming from json and it is not static Eg: abc="123" or it could be changed to abc="456". How can I store this variable with different values as an array in shared preferences and get the specific one?

Answer (score 3):

Shared preferences has the method `setStringList(String key, List<String> value)` and you can retrive those values with `getStringList(String key)`

Comment: Please could you provide an example code how you can store and how you can retrieve? Thanks a lot

Comment: `final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String abc = "123";
    final String key = "abcKey";
    prefs.setStringList(key, [abc]); //setting the string list
    final List<String> abcList = prefs.getStringList(key); //retriving the string list
    final String abc2 = "456";
    prefs.setStringList(key, prefs.getStringList(key)..add(abc2)); //adding another item to the string list`

Comment: is it possible to use same variable with different values ?